# Signing with Web3 and Metamask... what is the next step after getting accounts?

Tags: web3js, metamask

I have this so far

```
 const connectMetaMask = async () => {
        if (typeof window.ethereum !== 'undefined') {
            const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
            setWalletAddress(accounts[0])
        }
    }
```

which prompts the metamask extension to ask the user for pass to get eth accounts.

After this I want to work with some authentication using the public address, nonces etc, but I am at a road block

When it comes time to use the web3 library, specifically `web3.sign()` or whatever is ultimately required, I am lost.

How do I use metamask to ask the user to allow the accounts to be used by web3?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Once an account is approved its address will be provided to the app. Then depending on the objective you need to call web3.eth.sign or web3.eth.sendTransaction, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sign the message.

```js
window.signMessage = async (message, address) => {
    try {
        const signature = await window.web3.eth.personal.sign(message, address);
        return { signature, succeeded: true, reasonPhrase: null };
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return { signature: null, succeeded: false, reasonPhrase: error.message };
    }
};
```